# iPhone: How to upload screenshot for in app purchase review?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I go to Manage Your In App Purchases, select the In App Purchase and when I click "Approve" I get this message:

The following error(s) occurred:
 * You must upload a screenshot before approving an In App Purchase

I can't find where can I upload the screenshot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree, a screenshot of what?

Comment: Here's an image of the area where I'm suppose to upload the screenshot. There's no button. How do I upload it???... http://www.detour.co/personal/screenshot.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit the Edit button at the top of the screen, then there is an "Upload File" available.